# Cómo se cambia de estilo en un JavaScript según una condición

Tags: javascript, css

Estoy realizando una funcion en JavaScript que alimenta una tabla. Necesito darle estilo al resultado usando un condicional desde el mismo JavaScript.

No puedo usar el `document.getElement` y no sé cómo hacerlo.

Aquí, `resultado` contiene el valor que quiero mostrar.

```
if(r1<=r2){
    // necesito que este tenga un estilo definido
    cell.innerHTML = resultado;
}else{
    //y en este caso cambie
    cell.innerHTML =   resultado;
}
```

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. Podrías explicarte un poco mejor y agregar más código ?

Comment: Sí en resultado ya tienes lo que quieres, no podrias hacer resultado = "<p>" + resultado + "</p>" ? Y digo <p> como podrias ponerle un style inline

Comment: ¿Por que no puedes usar `document.getElement`?

Comment: ¿Qué estilo estás buscando cambiar? ¿Podrías mostrar cómo está tu HTML ahora y cómo debería quedar?

Comment: @Christian, Gracias! si la utilice y obtuve el estilo en la celda a insertar!.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero, no podía usarlo o no sabia como, ya que estaba generando las celdas en donde quería mostrar mi resultado dentro de la función de JavaScript de la siguiente manera:   cell = row.insertCell();  así que no tenia un elemento id que pudiera llamar con el document.getElement.

Comment: @BryantBarret perfecto, me alegra ver que pudiste solucionarlo. Saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te conviene agregar la biblioteca jQuery y definir clases CSS para cada resultado. Luego en la función usás los métodos addClass() o removeClass() de jQuery para agregar o quitar clases al tag html que tenga que variar.

Si no querés usar jQuery también podés modificar la clase de un elemento con el atributo className de js.

Para seleccionar elementos del DOM te recomiendo que les pongas id y luego uses getElementById() o bien $("#id") de jQuery.

Slds!

Comment: Hola @Nicolas. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por el aporte. ¿no crees que tu respuesta se podría beneficiar enormemente con un ejemplo de código. Pensemos que quienes pueden estar leyendo se están recién iniciando, y necesitan entender con ejemplos. La idea del sitio es aportar contenido con la mayor calidad posible.